# Multi-layered JSON object to CSV convertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a JSON-object to a CSV file in javascript.

I have used all kinds of libraries and pre-made functions, but nothing seems to work for me as soon as the JSON starts to nest.

This is one of the functions I am using:

```
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                if (line != '') line += ','

                line += array[i][index];
            }

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }

        return str;
    }
```

I have seen people say that the complexity of your json object should not be of influence to to your output, but all I am getting is: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc..

Online you can find json to csv converters that actually manage to create a nicely done csv file with extra headers if a property is double nested.
So any hints in the right direction of how I would write a function like this would be really appreciated. If you know of any libraries that can do this that would be great too!

(It is probably worth stating that when I use a single-layered json object the csv file won't show [object,Object] and instead gives me a nice csv file, its only when it starts to get nested that it doesnt work anymore)

UPDATE: As requested, this is the kind of JSON file im working with.

```
[
{
"HEADER": {
    "SEARCH": "Zoeken",
    "FILTER": "Filter",
    "MISC": "Overige"
},
   "FORM": {
    "REQUIRED": "Dit veld is verplicht",
    "MINLENGTH": "De input is te kort",
    "MAXLENGTH": "De input is te lang",
    "EMAIL": "Geen geldig e-mailadres"
},
"TODO": "TODO: Hier moet nog een leuke tekst komen! dit komt uit een vertaling, in dit geval Nederlands. Nu is Nederlands natuurlijk op dit moment de enige taal maar het zou mooi zijn als hier in de toekomst veer vertalingen bij komen..."
}
 ]
```

I also wanted to add that when I use 'agnes.js' I don't get [Object object] as output, but instead every single letter is added underneath each other and there are no more than 1 column.

Comment: please add an example of your object.

Comment: I tried your sample code.. I'm not getting `[object Object]`

Comment: @NinaScholz added example of my json

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen was your json also nested? Does it work with my sample json code too?

Comment: It won't work for nested json obviously. Because the `toString` method always returns `[object Object]` for an `object`. You can stringify it though.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen thanks for your help! however, when I stringify it, the output is placed like this: http://prntscr.com/cmgs0v, where all the letters are placed below each other. And when I download it as a csv file, it doesnt show any letters at all, just the brackets and colons...

Comment: Converting a nested object into CSV would depend on how many levels of nesting there is. Is the object structure consistent, or will it change in the future?

Comment: Yes the object structure is consistent, it's just a translation file so it is definitely possible to keep it like this.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRIVIAL SOLUTION**

```
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ',';

            // If array[i][index] is an object then we loop over its properties
            // And add it to the CSV string in a similar manner
            if (typeof array[i][index] === 'object') {
                var inner_obj = array[i][index];

                for (var index1 in inner_obj) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += '"' + inner_obj[index1] + '"';
                }
            } else {
                line += '"' + array[i][index] + '"';
            }
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

Since the object structure will remain consistent, what I did was run a `if-else` check to see if the `array[i][index]` is an object or not. If it is an object then we simply run a loop over its properties and add it to the CSV string like before.

Also, I placed quotes around all elements so that strings which have `,` don't get misinterpreted as the CSV's element separator.

Comment: Yay! atleast I'm getting values into the csv file now.. 
There is just one problem left though. All the titles are gone, its just 1 row now with all the individual titles. Would you know how to add this? Or doesn't my function add these in the first place?
I'm starting to think I should just remove the nesting and keeping it simpler.

Comment: By titles do you mean the headers? No, your function doesn't handle the headers.

Comment: @MaxTaylor you should upvote/accept this answer if it helped you.